# Okhttp: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

I am using Okhttp3 for consuming rest service with a proxy under-lined.

I have tried the following code but the exception is occuring i.e. java.net.UnknownHostException:

I tried to alter the proxy solution and changed the proxy address format but nothing founded. Please help.

```
int proxyPort = 8080;
                String proxyHost = "proxy";
                final String username = "user";
                final String password = "pass";
                okhttp3.Response response2 = null;

                SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
                SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();

                Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
                  @SuppressWarnings({ "null", "unused" })
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                       String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
                       return response2.request().newBuilder()
                           .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                           .build();
                  }

                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route arg0, okhttp3.Response arg1) throws IOException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
                };

                OkHttpClient c = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
                        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
                        .build();

                logger.info("FMS WEBSERVICE LOG >>> OkHttpClient " + c);

                okhttp3.MediaType mediaType = okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                logger.info("FMS WEBSERVICE LOG >>> mediaType " + mediaType);

                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=0146b9a4-7e99-4c83-8e9e-6049cfec55da&client_secret=nY3oL5xQ3bJ8yT3nC1nV5bY4mY6eW7yP1nY6dS6rQ2nE5iR0rM&scope=ABLApis");

                logger.info("FMS WEBSERVICE LOG >>> body " + body);

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                          .url("https://221.120.211.69:443/abl-api/uat/oauth2/token")
                          .post(body)
                          .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                          .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
                          .build();

                logger.info("FMS WEBSERVICE LOG >>> request " + request);

                        okhttp3.Response r = c.newCall(request).execute();

                        logger.info("FMS WEBSERVICE LOG >>> response " + r);

              } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

              } 
            return "a";

    }
```

Comment: I guess your proxy doesn't work and inaccessible by itself. And please don't provide logins and passwords in public

Comment: proxy details are correct. and sorry for that I updated my post, can you help me in the case? is my code fine?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I still think, that proxy is inaccessible from your machine. `nslookup yourproxyaddress` should show dns name if it's exists. `java.net.UnknownHostException` doesn't come from nowhere. I guess your network can't connect to the proxy by itself, even with the right code

Comment: I have deployed this code on my local weblogic server and my machine is behind proxy and its throwing above error. However, I have another machine which is directly accessed through external card i.e. proxy card hence I dont need a proxy bypass on that machine. I have deployed over that and it is giving: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 400

Comment: You can see that there are two different problems. First is that without proxy 400 http code means that you give the server wrong url/parameters. And the second problem is proxy on weblogic server either is inaccessible or your code is wrong.

Comment: You should solve your problems separately without interference. Remove proxy logic and test code where proxy is not needed. Then try to connect via ssh to your weblogic server and test if your proxy is available on your server (I guess it's not). And then test your code with proxy on any needed machine, but proxy must be accessible there

Comment: I have tested it without proxy and its giving me  java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 400.

Comment: I have crossed checked the url and params. They all are fine

Comment: I guess you can add `HttpLoggingInterceptor debugLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    debugLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);` `OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(debugLoggingInterceptor) ... then your code` to debug it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207846/discussion-between-eugene-kortov-and-jawad-dev).